# Trying to IEnumerable JSON Response Error

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, deserialization

I want to iterate through my JSON response in viewmodel MVC so I am trying to incorporate IEnumerable for this:

```
ArtistInfoResponse IMusicRepository.GetArtistResponse(string artistName)
{
    artistName = (char)34 + artistName + (char)34;
    RestClient client = new RestClient($"https://api.deezer.com/search?q=artist:{artistName}");

    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    if (response.IsSuccessful)
    {
        // Deserialize the string content into JToken object
        var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(response.Content);

        // Deserialize the JToken object into our ArtistInfoResponse Class
        return content.ToObject<ArtistInfoResponse>();
    }

    return null;
}
```

And I get this response:

```
From this Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'MyMusicApp.Models.ArtistInfoResponse' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'data'.'
```

Here is my class:

```
public class ArtistInfoResponse : IEnumerable
{
    public SongInfo[] Data { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public string Next { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your JSON string contain? Seems like a very similar problem to what I had earlier today. Solved it with this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n

Comment: You need to apply the `JsonObjectAttribute` to your type. The default serializer will assume any `IEnumerable` is to be serialized as an array.

Comment: Be able to enter part of Json data

Comment: I am able to get the JSON deserialized into my class, it's then displaying the information in my viewmodel and iterating over the JSON response to do so.  I thought I had to make it IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

The response itself is an object and not an array. You should not implement `IEnumerable` for your `ArtistInfoResponse` class. The response only contains an array for data wich you have implemented correctly as `SongInfo[]`.

*EDIT*: Here ist an example request for anyone who comes here:
https://api.deezer.com/search?q=artist:dire%20straits